# How do I execute a line of code ONLY after a method has finished?

Tags: ios, objective-c, completionhandler

I have a method `getSpotifyProductTypeWithSession:(SPTSession *)session` that I'm calling in viewDidLoad and I want the code below it to only be executed once `getSpotifyProductTypeWithSession:(SPTSession *)session` has finished. How do I do this? Here's my code below.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{

SPTAuth *auth = [SPTAuth defaultInstance];

    [self getSpotifyProductTypeWithSession:auth.session];


        BOOL hasPremium = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"hasPremium"];

        if (hasPremium) {
            [FireStarter setSpotifyHasPremium];
        } else {
            [FireStarter setSpotifyHasFree];
        }

}

-(void)getSpotifyProductTypeWithSession:(SPTSession *)session{

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    [SPTUser requestCurrentUserWithAccessToken:session.accessToken callback:^(NSError *error, SPTUser *user) {

        [defaults setBool:NO forKey:@"hasPremium"];
        [defaults synchronize];

        switch (user.product) {
            case SPTProductFree:
                [defaults setBool:NO forKey:@"hasPremium"];
                [defaults synchronize];
                break;
            case SPTProductPremium:
                [defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"hasPremium"];
                [defaults synchronize];
                break;
            case SPTProductUnlimited:
                [defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"hasPremium"];
                [defaults synchronize];
            default:

                break;
        }
    }];

    NSLog(@"%@",[defaults objectForKey:@"hasPremium"]);
}
```

Comment: You need a completion handler.

Comment: FYI - Don't compare a `BOOL` value to `NO` or `YES`. Simply do: `if (hasPremium) { // do stuff } else { // do other stuff }`.

Comment: Since you don't want to explain what getSpotifyProductTypeWithSession:auth.session does, you should direct your question to Spotify or whoever.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks, how do I add a simple completion block? `getSpotifyProductTypeWithSession` is  checking whether or not a user has a premium account and then changing an NSUserDefaults key to reflect that. I don't want to run either of the methods below until that check has been made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to add a completion handler parameter to your `getSpotifyProductTypeWithSession` method. Then you can move your code inside the completion handler. It would also help to have the completion handler tell you the result so you don't need to check `NSUserDefaults` again.

Here's the added parameter:

```
-(void)getSpotifyProductTypeWithSession:(SPTSession *)session completion:(void (^)(BOOL hasPremium))completion {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    [SPTUser requestCurrentUserWithAccessToken:session.accessToken callback:^(NSError *error, SPTUser *user) {
        BOOL hasPremium = NO;

        switch (user.product) {
            case SPTProductFree:
                hasPremium = NO;
                break;
            case SPTProductPremium:
            case SPTProductUnlimited:
                hasPremium = YES;
                break;
        }

        [defaults setBool:hasPremium forKey:@"hasPremium"];

        if (completion) {
            completion(hasPremium);
        }
    }];
}
```

And here is how you call it:

```
[self getSpotifyProductTypeWithSession:auth.session completion:^(BOOL hasPremium) {
    if (hasPremium) {
        [FireStarter setSpotifyHasPremium];
    } else {
        [FireStarter setSpotifyHasFree];
    }
}];
```

There may be some typos. This code was not compiled and tested but it gives the idea.

Answer (score 1):

In order to play nice with methods that do async work and take completion blocks, you should adopt the same approach in your code.  So you might declare something like:

```
-(void)getSpotifyProductTypeWithSession:(SPTSession *)session completion:(void (^)(NSError *))completion {
    // ... OP code
    [SPTUser requestCurrentUserWithAccessToken:session.accessToken callback:^(NSError *error, SPTUser *user) {
        // if there's an error
        if (error) completion(error);
        // ....more OP code
        // at the end
        completion(nil);   // we're done with no error
    }];
}
```

Now your call to this follows the same pattern...

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    SPTAuth *auth = [SPTAuth defaultInstance];
    [self getSpotifyProductTypeWithSession:auth.session completion:^(NSError *)error {
        BOOL hasPremium = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"hasPremium"];
       // and so on...
    }];
```